# What is the equivalent of @Value in CDI world?

Tags: java, spring, properties, dependency-injection, cdi

What is the way one inject property value from property placeholder into CDI bean?

In Spring one write:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value("${webservice.user}")
private String webserviceUser;
```

what sets the `webserviceUser` field to property `webservice.user` from property file/property placeholder.

How to do that with CDI? I've tried to find some answer, but I couldn't find any equivalent. However, people write, you can use CDI as Spring substitute on application servers, and that use case is very basic, so surely there must be an easy way, unfortunately I've failed to find it.

Comment: Could you tried with @Inject ?

Comment: There is no direct alternative, however you can find an attempt at implementation [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/06/inject-java-properties-in-java-ee-using-cdi/).

Comment: @DmitryKuskov Thaks, I'll look at that, but I see that claims that CDI is full replacement of Spring are highly exaggerated, if you have to write the most basic things from scratch. I must consult PM if sparing a few MB on EAR size is worth such effort.

Comment: I'm curious, where have you read that CDI is a full replacement of spring? I'd argue that it's a replacement for Spring core IoC, but you should look to addons like DeltaSpike for more features beyond that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CDI is a specification about Dependecy Injection and Context so it doesn't have such configuration things out of the box. But it also provides a very powerful extension mechanism that allows third party projects to add new portable features (i.e that works with all CDI implementation and that are not tied to a server).
The most important project providing CDI extensions is [Apache Deltaspike](http://deltaspike.apache.org) and good news, it provides what you need.

So you need to add deltaspike-core in your project. If you use Maven, you need to add this dependencies to your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that if you don't care about your properties filename, just add `META-INF/apache-deltaspike.properties` to your project and put your properties in it. If you need more than one file or want to choose the name you'll have to implement `PropertyFileConfig` interface for each file like this :

```
public class MyCustomPropertyFileConfig implements PropertyFileConfig
{
    @Override
    public String getPropertyFileName()
    {
        return "myconfig.properties";
    }
}
```

After that you'll be able to inject values like this

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SomeRandomService
{
    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "endpoint.poll.interval")
    private Integer pollInterval;

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "endpoint.poll.servername")
    private String pollUrl;

    ...
 }
```

As you see in this example taken from Deltaspike documentation, you can inject your value in String but also in Integer, Long, Float, Boolean fields. You could provide your own type if you need something more specific.
Deltaspike config documentation can be found [here](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/configuration.html).